# snmptrapd_handler.c and netsnmp_pdu (Trap receiver implementation)

Tags: c, net-snmp

I made a trap receiver application. I just only modified the snmptrapd_handler in the next way:

```
int   print_handler(   netsnmp_pdu           *pdu,
                       netsnmp_transport     *transport,
                       netsnmp_trapd_handler *handler)
{

     int iii= ems_flush_traps(pdu,transport);
         return NETSNMPTRAPD_HANDLER_OK;

}

int ems_flush_traps(netsnmp_pdu *pdu, netsnmp_transport *transport) {
    display(pdu,transport);
    return 0;
}

int display(netsnmp_pdu *pdu, netsnmp_transport *transport) {

    oid OID1[]={1,3,6,1,4,1,24024,200,200,1};
    oid OID2[]={1,3,6,1,4,1,24024,200,200,2};
    oid OID4[]={1,3,6,1,4,1,24024,200,200,4};

    netsnmp_variable_list *vars;
    char alarmaName[40];
    char dateIn[40];
    //long  id[40];
    long idSeverity[40];
    char strIdSeverity[2];
    char strTime[20];
    char clean[] = "";
    netsnmp_pdu * internal_pdu;

    internal_pdu = snmp_clone_pdu(pdu);

    int ii=0;
    char stringBuffer[20];
    for (vars =  internal_pdu->variables; vars != NULL; vars = vars->next_variable){
            // Alarm name

             if(memcmp(OID1, vars->name_loc, sizeof(OID1))==0){
                    memcpy (alarmaName, vars->val.string, strlen(vars->val.string)+1);
                    printf("alarm Name: %s\n",alarmaName);
                    printf("alarm Name: %s\n",vars->val.string);
                    //memcpy ( vars->val.string, clean, strlen(clean)+1 );
                    //vars->val.string=NULL;

            }

             if(memcmp(OID2, vars->name_loc, sizeof(OID2))==0){
                    memcpy (idSeverity, vars->val.integer, sizeof(vars->val.integer) );
                    sprintf(strIdSeverity, "%lu", idSeverity[0]);
                    printf("Severity: %s\n",strIdSeverity);
                    printf("Severity: %lu\n",vars->val.integer[0]);
             }

             if(memcmp(OID4, vars->name_loc, sizeof(OID4))==0){
                  memcpy ( dateIn , vars->val.string, strlen(vars->val.string)+1 );
                  printf("Date: %s\n",dateIn);
                  printf("Date: %s\n",vars->val.string);
                  //memcpy ( vars->val.string, clean, strlen(clean)+1 );
                  //vars->val.string=NULL;
             }

             //strcpy(vars->val.string, "");


    }


        free(vars);
        snmp_free_pdu( internal_pdu );
            return 0;

}
```

with the next commands line i executed several times the program:

```
$ sudo snmptrapd -f -Le -F "%v\n"

$ sudo snmptrap -v 2c -c public 192.168.0.40 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.24024.200.200.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.24024.200.200.1 s latenciawan 1.3.6.1.4.1.24024.200.200.2 i 2 1.3.6.1.4.1.24024.200.200.3 s MINOR 1.3.6.1.4.1.24024.200.200.4 s "2013/02/18 15:36:00"
```

the result was:

```
alarm Name: latenciawan
alarm Name: latenciawan
Severity: 2
Severity: 2
Date: 2013/02/18 15:36:00
Date: 2013/02/18 15:36:00
```

and after several executions i have some times the wrong result:

```
alarm Name: latenciawan15:36:00
alarm Name: latenciawan15:36:00
Severity: 2
Severity: 2
Date: 2013/02/18 15:36:00
Date: 2013/02/18 15:36:00
```

Comment: Seems as if `vars->val.string` is messed up in the first place. Do you have code where this variable gets set up? Also, you may want to try using the `val_size` member of the `vars` struct to limit the string length.

Comment: Ok with string length it works,...thanks! but i would like to solve the problem in vars->val.string.